# What is best way of adding a hidden input in code below

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of code below where it contains buttons and each button contains its own hidden input:

```
<?php
$a = range("A","Z");
?>

<table id="answerSection">
<tr>

<?php
$i = 1;
foreach($a as $key => $val){
    if($i%7 == 1) echo"<tr><td>";
    echo"<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"btnclick(this);\" value=\"$val\" id=\"answer".$val."\" name=\"answer".$val."Name\" class=\"answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff\">";
    echo"<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"1\" id=\"hiddenAnswer".$val."\" name=\"hidden".$val."\" class=\"onButtons\">";
    if($i%7 == 0) echo"</td></tr>";
    $i++;
}
?>
</tr>
```

But what I want to do is copy this control using jquery when the control is appended into a table row. I have done 90% of it but my question is what is the best way to be able to add the hidden inputs for each button in the code below:

```
function insertQuestion(form) {   

            var context = $('#answerSection');
    var currenttotal = context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length;        



    var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
    var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'>");
    var $td = $("<td class='extratd'>");
    var $answer = $("<div class='answer'>3. Answer:<br/></div>");


var $this, i=0, $row, $cell;
$('#optionAndAnswer .answers').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    if(i%7 == 0) {
        $row = $("<tr/>").appendTo($answer);
        $cell = $("<td/>").appendTo($row);
    }
    var $newBtn = $("<input class='answerBtnsRow answers' type='button' style='display:%s;' onclick='btnclick(this);' />".replace('%s',$this.is(':visible')?'inline-block':'none')).attr('name', $this.attr('name')).attr('value', $this.val()).attr('class', $this.attr('class')).attr('id', $this.attr('id')+'Row');

    $newBtn.appendTo($cell);

    i++;
});


    $tr.append($td);
    $td.append($answer);
    $tbody.append($tr); 


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var elem = $(this)
var $newBtn =
        $(document.createElement('input'), {
            type : 'button',
            onclick : 'btnclick(this);',
            name : elem.attr('name'),
            value : elem.val(),
            class : elem.attr('class'),
            id : elem.attr('id') + 'Row'
          },
          css : {
               display : elem.is('visible') ? 'inline-block' : 'none'
          }
        );
$newBtn.appendTo($cell);
```

Comment: That looks a lot cleaner, but how do I add the hidden input with this button input, at each button has its own hidden input like the top code in my question

Comment: But I don't think that would give me the same hidden input control as the one on top of the code. Let me post the whole code so you can see what I am trying to do

Comment: I have editted the code to include the whole code. What I am trying to do is append the buttons from the top to each table row, but I want the same controls from the buttons to appear in the appended rows. Now I have done it for the buttons if you look at the editted code but how do I do it for the hidden input as well? Each button has its own hidden input